# How to export a txt file in rows with the same category in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, export

I need to export all the Grid that is one file per row, but if they have the same category, export each row within a same txt file, if at all Grid there is only one file with category 8 for example, that row will be a txt file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to create different text file for each category group. 
Try this:

```
  private void SaveToTextFIle()
    {
        //get all distinct categories
        DataView view = new DataView((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
        DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "CategoryID");

        //save each category
        foreach (DataRow categoryRow in distinctValues.Rows)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            //if you want headers
            var headers = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", headers.Select(column => "\"" + column.HeaderText + "\"").ToArray()));

            //form actual data available for this category
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["CategoryID"].Value.ToString() == categoryRow["CategoryID"].ToString()))
            {
                var cells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>();
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", cells.Select(cell => "\"" + cell.Value + "\"").ToArray()));
            }

            //write to file
            File.WriteAllText(@"D:\" + categoryRow["CategoryID"] + ".txt", sb.ToString());
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get this problem: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: probably with the datgridview source.. How you are assigning data to datagridview?

Comment: here it gives me the error: foreach (DataGridViewRow row in TablaDatos.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["CategoryID"].Value.ToString() == categoryRow["CategoryID"].ToString()))

Comment: Is there any empty/NULL values in "CategoryID"?

Comment: No nulls, all rows are data CategoryID, but the DataGridView is empty at the end of a row, if that last row serious error, as it could prevent me take that last line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105079/discussion-between-abregow-and-olivarsham).

Comment: this may happen if you set the `AllowUserToAddRows` property of `DataGridView` to `true`. Set it `false` and try again

Comment: Works! thank you very much for your great help me served much